# R split a column in this format

Tags: r, split, strsplit

I need to split out this column into 2 columns

- 5/5/2020Tom Tesla

desired outcome is

- Col1                   Col2
- 5/5/2020               Tom Tesla

I have tried strAny but need help as Col 1 is not a fixed with as the  date field length varies due to 1 or 2 characters for the day of the month.
Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `separate` with a regex lookaround to split between a digit and a lower case letter

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, 'col1', into = c('date', 'other'), sep="(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])")
#     date             other
#1  1/1/2000            yogurt
#2  1/1/2000      toilet paper
#3  2/1/2000              soda
#4 11/1/2000            bagels
#5 12/1/2000            fruits
#6 13/1/2000 laundry detergent
```

---

Or using `base R` with `strsplit`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df1$col1),
      "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", perl = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("1/1/2000yogurt", "1/1/2000toilet paper", 
"2/1/2000soda", "11/1/2000bagels", "12/1/2000fruits", "13/1/2000laundry detergent"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways :

Using `extract` from `tidyr` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, col1, c('col1', 'col2'), regex = '(.*\\d)(.*)')
```

---

Or with `dplyr` and `stringr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(col2 = str_extract(col1, '\\d+/\\d+/\\d+'), 
         col3 = str_remove(col1, col2))
```